# How access to google drive appdata with expressjs + node

Tags: node.js, express, google-drive-api

Hi I 'm trying this web app https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication
and works well.

I try to access with my google credential and it works well.
My needs is to save in appdata (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata) folder in google drive some data, but I've try to access using this npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-drive) and I've the follow answer:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission" } }
```

so I access to my google console but I not understand how to add  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder" permission

I 've also googled for enable access to user google drive but now google dev console is really changed from example so ... I dunno how to give permission to my web app to write some file in user google drive.

thanks